# A little problem with functions and arrays

Tags: c

I'm doing a program that check if 5 numbers that the user insert are even or odd, then they will be stored into an array and finally these values will be printed out on screen. In order to do this i've divided this program in two functions just to understand how the functions and the arrays works together, but it doesn't print the values that i've putted in. Why?

```
int check_even_and_odd(int number, int list[]){

printf("Insert the numbers\n");
scanf("%d", &list[number]);

if (number % 2 == 0) {
    printf("Even\n");
}
else{
    printf("Odd\n");
}
return 0;
}

int main () {
int k;
int i = 0;
int list2[5] = {0};

while (i < 5) {
    i++;
    k = check_even_and_odd(i, &list2[i]);
}

i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    i++;
    printf("\n%d\n", list2[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Edit: Now that the main issue is gone, I want to add a little improvement to this little project. I want that the program tells to me how many Even or Odd number are in the array, but i don't know how to do it. I was thinking about adding 2 counters into the `if` statement (one for the even number and one for the odd numbers) but once i do this i don't know how to continue.

The program with the counters is this:

```
void check_even_and_odd(int number, int list[]){

int even = 0;
int odd = 0;

printf("Insert the numbers\n");
scanf("%d", &list[number]);

if (number % 2 == 0) {

    even++;
}
else{
    odd++;
}
printf("Even numbers are: %d\n", even);
printf("Odd numbers are: %d\n", odd);
}

int main () {
int i = 0;
int list2[5] = {0};

while (i < 5) {
    i++;
    check_even_and_odd(i, list2);
}

i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    i++;
    printf("\n%d\n", list2[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Obviously it isn't complete, but as i have already said, i don't know how to continue

Comment: You declare `int list2[5] = {0}`. It has size 5 but only 1 value.

Comment: @AerysS actually that's allowed. The extra values are 0. (so the first one is 0 because it says so, and the rest are 0 automatically)

Comment: You are passing `list2+i` as the second argument of `check_even_and_odd`, but in that function you are treating that argument as if it is just `list2`.  Also, you increment i too early and wind up indexing the array as 1..5 instead of 0..4

Comment: IOW, either pass `list2` and use `&list[number]` as the argument to scanf, or pass `&list2[i]` but then just use `list` as the argument to scanf

Comment: @Sub0Zero1990 editing a question which already has an accepted answer and adding to it a new question is not the way to go, not only it does not comply with site guidelines but it also draws much less attention to it, you'd do better removing this edit and asking a brand new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void check_even_and_odd(int number, int list[], unsigned int *even_count)
{
    printf("Insert the numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &list[number]);

    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        printf("Even\n");
        *even_count += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Odd\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int even_count;
    int i = 0;
    int list2[5] = {0};

    while (i < 5)
    {
        check_even_and_odd(i, list2, &even_count);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < 5)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n", list2[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("There are %d even numbers and %d odd ones.\n", even_count, 5 - even_count);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, your main problem is in passing the list to the function in `k = check_even_and_odd(i, &list2[i]);`, as you should be passing the entire list, not a specific number in the list.

Comment: Just a question, if i would add the possibility to say how many even and odd number are in the array, what should i do? I was thinking to add two counter (one for the even numbers and one for the odd numbers) into the `if` statement so they will raise by one for each even or odd numbers they count, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Like this  `if (number % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
    }
    else{
        odd++;
    }
    printf("The even numbers are: %d: \n", even);
}`

Comment: @Sub0Zero1990 I have edited my answer to include all of your requirements. For your _even_ and _odd_ numbers count problem, I have created an `even_count` variable that gets passed by reference to the `check_even_and_odd` function and is incremented every time there is an even number. At the end, the number of even numbers is `even_count` and the number of odd ones is `5 - even_count`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function expects an array argument but you are passing the address of individual elements of the array, so it won't work properly, you'll just need to use the correct argument:

```
 k = check_even_and_odd(i, list2);
```

Quibble: `k` is never used so you don't really need it. You can just make your function `void` and remove the variable:

```
void check_even_and_odd(int number, int list[]){

    printf("Insert the numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &list[number]);

    if (number % 2 == 0){
        printf("Even\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Odd\n");
    }
}

int main(){

    int i = 0;
    int list2[5] = {0};

    while (i < 5){
        i++;
        check_even_and_odd(i, list2);
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < 5){
        i++;
        printf("\n%d\n", list2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: About the quibble, how can i replace the k variable?

Comment: @DavideCamporeale, you may just remove it, a function returning a value doesn't need to be assigned. or you can make your function void, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Oh, now i understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your fault is in line `scanf("%d", &list[number]);` just need to change it to `scanf("%d", &list);` but i think you are miss understanding whole array and pointer logic. You can't pass list as argument and if you do that, The compiler will changed it to pointer automatically. So if you want to tell a function about your list you just have to pass it your list address in memory (*pointer*). So you should do it like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int How_Many_Odd = 0;
int How_Many_Even = 0;

void Add_To_List(int Number, int *ListIndex){   
    printf(
        "Number %d is %s\n",
        Number,
        (Number % 2 == 0)? "Even": "Odd" // check if is odd or even
    );
    
    if(Number % 2 == 0)
        How_Many_Even++;
    else
        How_Many_Odd++;
    

    // changing value of pointer ListIndex to Number
    *ListIndex = Number;
}

int main(){
    // first creating integer array with size of 5
    int List[5];

    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        // waiting for user to enter number
        int value;
        scanf("%d", &value);

        // changing value of index 0 to 3
        Add_To_List(value, &List[i]);
    }

    // showing how many odds and how many evens
    printf("%d numbers are even and %d numbers are odd\n", How_Many_Even, How_Many_Odd);

    // you can show every index value too
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("value of index %d is %d\n", i, List[i]);
    

    return 0;
}
```

I recommend you to learn about **pointer** that will fix your issues

Comment: Just a question, if i would add the possibility to say how many even and odd number are in the array, what should i do? I was thinking to add two counter (one for the even numbers and one for the odd numbers) into the `if` statement so they will raise by one for each even or odd numbers they count, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the tip about the pointer :)

Comment: open new question if is possible, in this comment area i cannot write code lines

Comment: you have to put the code into `` these things `printf("Hello")`

Comment: About the code that you wrote, i've tried to run it but there isn't any loop in it and i haven't the possibility to add any number, it only print the value that is already in the code as 'default' (3 in this case) and tells me that is odd. How can i fix this?

Comment: I'm working on Xcode and when i try to run the program it doesn't start. There isn't any error, but it simply doesn't start

Comment: Hmmm, It doesn't give you any more info?

Comment: Nope, nothing more nothing less. I don't understand why

Comment: Make sure that your inputs be like `1` and `Enter`, and again `2` and `Enter` and etc.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that when i run the program nothing happens

Comment: So you run it and then it crashes, You entering nothing? and it crashes?

Comment: How could i explain this... When i click the "run" button, Xcode builds the program but doesn't execute it

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
if (number % 2 == 0) {
```

This is checking the passed in parameter rather than the value entered by the user.  Suggest:

```
...
if( (list[number] % 2) == 0 )
{
    printf( "%s\n", "number is even" );
....
```